# Circle bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-animation

How can I make a button like this with Flutter? I tried a few solutions, checked pub.dev but I couldn't get a solution.

Button:

[image]

OnPressed:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this package: [circular_menu](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_menu)